# Address bar should be disabled in Kiosk mode for Metro IE

Tags: internet-explorer, kiosk

I want to use Metro IE in Kiosk mode, but restricting the user's ability to navigate to other URLs. The address bar should be disabled completely. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Kiosk Mode in Internet Explorer
>
> > Internet Explorer has a default Kiosk Mode, so you do not need to go to Metro Mode.
>
> How to Open Any Website in Kiosk Mode?
>
> > Start > Run
> >     Type iexplore -k www.microsoft.com
>
> What Happens to Address Bar ?
>
> > Address bar is pre disabled, Kiosk Mode will Open only 1 site and any URL inside main URL.

You can learn More Configuration on Kiosk Mode at below sources

http://www.ingenuityworking.com/knowledge/w/knowledgebase/internet-explorer-kiosk-mode.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780